# How can I remove duplicate string with Python?

Tags: python, string, duplicates

I am to learn python, I have a problem to deal with
Following example:

```
string1 = "Galaxy S S10 Lite"
string2 = "Galaxy Note Note 10 Plus"
```

How can I remove the second two duplicates "S" and "S" or "Note" and "Note"?

The result should look like

```
string1a = "Galaxy S10 Lite"
string2a = "Galaxy Note 10 Plus"
```

how to only the second duplicates should be removed and the sequence of the words should not be changed!

Comment: I would use split and drop the second position of the array.

Comment: @Capie There's no guarantee the word is always in the second place, I'd assume.

Comment: "S" and "S10" aren't the same word. There's no magical function that could just assume that and do what you want.

Comment: @AKX Don't assume so fast and let the author answer. Seems to me that he's getting 2 strings, where the first string is the first 2 items, and the scond string is the last 2 items.

Comment: The structure is always like string1 or string2, I just want to remove the 1 2 consecutive identical words in the second and third position and the output will look like string1a or string2a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string1a = string1.split()
del string1a[1]
string1a = " ".join(string1a)
```

This does what you want for the 2 strings provided.
It will only work in all the strings you want, if you know for sure that the second and third words of the string are the duplicates, giving preference to the third one.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer only removes the second word in the sentence manually.
If you have a very long string that will be very tedious to clean.

I assume there were only two cases:

1. Skip the letter if it's the same with the following word's first letter
2. Skip the word if it's the same as the its following word

This function can clean them automatically

```
def clean_string(string):
    """Clean if there were sequentially duplicated word or letter"""
    following_word = ''
    complete_words = []
    # loop through the string in reverse to be able to skip the earlier word/letter
    # string.split() splits your string by each space and make it as a list
    for word in reversed(string.split()):
        # to skip duplicated letter, in your case is to skip "S" and retain "S10"
        if (len(word) == 1) and (following_word[0] == word):
            following_word = word
            continue
        # to skip duplicated word, in your case is to skip "Note" and retain latter "Note"
        elif word == following_word:
            following_word = word
            continue
        following_word = word
        complete_words.append(word)
    # join all appended word and re-reverse it to be the expected sequence
    return ' '.join(reversed(complete_words))
```